# Set value of entire column in respect to copied data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that copies data from one workbook and outputs it into a table in another workbook. I just need the value of column "U" in correspondence to the copied rows to have a set value of "30". I would like to have this code written at the end of the copy/paste code so that it all works together in one sub.

Code for the copying/pasting:

```
Sub InsertData()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim DefCopyLastRow As Long, DefDestLastRow As Long


'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Warranty Template.xlsm").Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("QA Matrix Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Plant Sheet")

'1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
DefCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Row



'2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column D
'Offset property moves down 1 row
DefDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row



'3. Copy & Paste Data
wsCopy.Range("A5:A" & DefCopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("D" & DefDestLastRow)

wsCopy.Range("B5:B" & DefCopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("E" & DefDestLastRow)

wsCopy.Range("B5:B" & DefCopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("F" & DefDestLastRow)

wsCopy.Range("D5:D" & DefCopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("I" & DefDestLastRow)

wsCopy.Range("E5:E" & DefCopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("L" & DefDestLastRow)

wsDest.Range("U12:U" & DefDestLastRow).Value = 30
End Sub
```

I tried adding the last line before the "End Sub" but that doesn't seem to do the trick...

Picture of outputted data in table:
[image]

Comment: `Range("U12:U" & DefDestLastRow)` ends where you are starting the paste if I understand correctly?

Comment: @SJR `Range("L" & DefDestLastRow)` should be the end of the copy/pasting

Comment: What I was getting at is as per AAA's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to recalculate the last row. Recall that the last time you calculated it was to get the offset *before you pasted anything*. So replace your last line with this:

```vb
NewLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
wsDest.Range("U" & DefDestLastRow & ":U" & NewLastRow).Value = 30
```

**Your amended code:**

```vb
Sub InsertData()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim DefCopyLastRow As Long, DefDestLastRow As Long, NewLastRow As Long


'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
Set wsCopy = Workbooks("Warranty Template.xlsm").Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set wsDest = Workbooks("QA Matrix Template.xlsm").Worksheets("Plant Sheet")

'1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
DefCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Row

'2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column D
'Offset property moves down 1 row
DefDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row


'3. Copy & Paste Data
wsCopy.Range("A5:B" & DefCopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("D" & DefDestLastRow)

wsCopy.Range("B5:B" & DefCopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("F" & DefDestLastRow)

wsCopy.Range("D5:D" & DefCopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("I" & DefDestLastRow)

wsCopy.Range("E5:E" & DefCopyLastRow).Copy _
wsDest.Range("L" & DefDestLastRow)

NewLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
wsDest.Range("U" & DefDestLastRow & ":U" & NewLastRow).Value = 30

End Sub
```

Comment: one quick question: this works if the pasted data is always from "U12" cell down. How do I make it so that it always makes the value of column U = 30 for ONLY the rows that are pasted, no matter where they are outputted?